# Using ubuntu usb drive when dealing with windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu-10.04, usb-storage

I work as a contractor and would ideally like to stay working in a linux environment.

I would like to use linux on my windows workstation but don't have the permissions to change the OS, install software etc.

Can I use a linux usb stick to get things done - while not installing anything on the local machine?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/ is the answer to your prayers.